# UEFI install UBUNTU 14.04 Along Windows 8 (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8, uefi, system-installation

I have a preinstalled windows 8.1 with secure boot on.
i installed ubuntu 14.04 in uefi after which it showed the boot menu for first time, then i booted into windows and then when i started the pc next day(following shutdown) it booted directly into windows.
I need to install ubuntu 14.04 on it properly.Please help me through this by possibly giving a detailed order of steps to follow.
Thank You

Comment: In the BIOS settings, change UEFI to LEGACY and turn off the secure-boot. Now, boot the Ubuntu.I too have sony vaio with win 8 pre-installed. it worked for me.

Comment: Simply put, you want to check your UEFI bootloader firmware menu, and make sure that it has a "ubuntu" entry, and that it is at the top or the default.

Answer (score 0):

First you could try to restore the bootloader by using this live cd: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ 
If that doesn't work, the non complicated order would be:
1. Install Windows
2. Install Ubuntu
The GRUB bootloader detects other OS at install.
Also make sure if you are installing from USB make sure the bootloader doesn't get installed on your USB stick. Happend to me already several times.
More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 there is a menu to boot to another OS or to BIOS setting (because of the missing boot time). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGiG1oljjZI (thats the first video I found to that).

Then we have to know more about your mainboard to maybe help you. But the boot-repair tool mentioned can help. You can even install/run it running a live cd. Worked for me prio to trusty tahr 14.04.